# How can I execute a VBScript remotely using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, remoting, invoke-command

I have a VBScript to set the Internet Explorer as default browser. I want to execute that VBScript remotely using PowerShell. I have tried the following command:

```bsh
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName  -ScriptBlock { 
    Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c cscript.exe 
    C:\Users\mani\Desktop\test.vbs"
} -Credential $MySecureCreds
```

I also have tried the following:

```bsh
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock { 
    cscript.exe C:\Users\mani\Desktop\test.vbs"
} -Credential $MySecureCreds
```

The *test.vbs* code is as follows:

```vb
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms 
/page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Internet%20Explorer"
WScript.Sleep 1200
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.Popup " Internet Explorer set as Default Browser Successfully!!!. ", 3, "Default Browser"
WScript.Quit
```

However, by using the above commands, the default browser is not changing. If I manually run the VBScript it works though. How can I execute the VBScript remotely?

Comment: You should have got error messages on both Powershell tries.. Mainly, your quoting is incorrect.

Comment: It's not possible that any of the code you posted could run successfully anywhere. The VBScript has a line break in a string, which is invalid syntax. On top of that the 1st PowerShell snippet has a line break which would first run `cmd.exe /c cscript.exe` (without script) and and then `C:\Users\mani\Desktop\test.vbs` with `wscript.exe`, and the 2nd snippet has a trailing double quote. Please copy/paste your actual code, not something you fabricated or typed from memory.

Comment: Also, when using `Invoke-Command` you don't have a foreground window that you could `SendKeys` to, so I doubt that your approach will work remotely at all. You'll probably need to find out which registry setting is modified and then change that.

Comment: You could pull the relevant parts from this project: https://github.com/sampalmer/set-default-browser and just do it in powershell. It doesn't look easy, though.